How to find all the possible products from a list of commutative $2 \times 2$ matrices?
Say if I have a list of commutative $2 \times 2$ matrices. I'll call these $2 \times 2$ matrices $A, B, C, D$.
Mylist=List[A,B,C,D]

Say if I want to find all possible multiplicative combinations of the elements of my list, resulting in: $$A,B,C,D,AA,BB,CC,DD,AB,AC,AD,BC,BD,CD,ABC,ABD,BCD,ABCD$$
How would I do this using mathematica?
I can get any combination of $2$ and any combination of $3$ and any combination of $4$ using
2combo=Table[Mylist[[i]].Mylist[[j]],{i,4},{j,4}]
3combo=Table[Mylist[[i]].Mylist[[j]].Mylist[[k]],{i,4},{j,4},{k,4}]
4combo=Table[Mylist[[i]].Mylist[[j]].Mylist[[k]].Mylist[[l]],{i,4},{j,4},{k,4},{l,4}]

and then I could join these together using:
Join[Mylist,2combo,3combo,4combo]

But there are several shortcomings to this method:

It is clunky. I would prefer to be able to do it with one line of code
The order of the multiplication for the matrices does not matter as they are commutative so the table approach, which will calculate AB and BA creates too many unnecessary duplicative values.


Try this one-liner
Subsets[Dot[a, b, c, d], {1, 4}]
(*{a, b, c, d, a . b, a . c, a . d, b . c, b . d, c . d, a . b . c, 
 a . b . d, a . c . d, b . c . d, a . b . c . d}*)

If repeated entries are needed, you can construct them as
Join[{a, b, c, d}, 
 Join[Table[
    Select[Tuples[Dot[a, b, c, d], i], OrderedQ], {i, 2, 4}]] // 
  Flatten]
(* {a, b, c, d, a . a, a . b, a . c, a . d, b . b, b . c, b . d, c . c, 
 c . d, d . d, a . a . a, a . a . b, a . a . c, a . a . d, a . b . b, 
 a . b . c, a . b . d, a . c . c, a . c . d, a . d . d, b . b . b, 
 b . b . c, b . b . d, b . c . c, b . c . d, b . d . d, c . c . c, 
 c . c . d, c . d . d, d . d . d, a . a . a . a, a . a . a . b, 
 a . a . a . c, a . a . a . d, a . a . b . b, a . a . b . c, 
 a . a . b . d, a . a . c . c, a . a . c . d, a . a . d . d, 
 a . b . b . b, a . b . b . c, a . b . b . d, a . b . c . c, 
 a . b . c . d, a . b . d . d, a . c . c . c, a . c . c . d, 
 a . c . d . d, a . d . d . d, b . b . b . b, b . b . b . c, 
 b . b . b . d, b . b . c . c, b . b . c . d, b . b . d . d, 
 b . c . c . c, b . c . c . d, b . c . d . d, b . d . d . d, 
 c . c . c . c, c . c . c . d, c . c . d . d, c . d . d . d, 
 d . d . d . d} *)


As it is explicitly stated the matrices are commutative you could use:
pol = Total[Table[(a+b+c+d)^j, {j,
4}]];
cr = Keys[CoefficientRules[pol]];
Times@@@({a,b,c,d}^#&/@cr)


If you want more than form of products but potential to replace with the matrices:
Dot@@@(({a,b,c,d}^#&/@cr)/. 1->Nothing)


Just if ultimately going to use x/.{a->matrix,...}. Exponentiation in previous output would exponential components and not matrix.
Grid[Partition[
  Sort[Dot @@@ (Table[a, #[[1]]]~Join~Table[b, #[[2]]]~Join~
        Table[c, #[[3]]]~Join~Table[d, #[[4]]] & /@ cr)], UpTo[4]], 
 Frame -> All]


